# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

```
I have embedded an applet (jar file)in a html page
```

Now when I am trying to access the web page , it is giving the following error.

```
<APPLET CODE="com.xxx.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber" NAME="Read" ID="Read" MAYSCRIPT alt="Photo Id"   ARCHIVE="\test.jar, \ojdbc14.signed.jar, \ojdbc14_g.signed.jar" WIDTH="100%"  HEIGHT="100%"  HSPACE="1"  VSPACE="1">
</APPLET>




load: class com.xxx.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://localhost/popit/POPit/com/xxx/tru/ReadNFCSerialNumber.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 7 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: `open HTTP connection failed:http://localhost/popit/POPit/com/xxx/tru/ReadNFCSerialNumber.class` there you go

Comment: can u be more specific? i didnt got wt u meant

Answer (score 1):

The web browser is trying to load your class from the URI `http://localhost/popit/POPit/com/xxx/tru/ReadNFCSerialNumber.class` instead of your jar file. The contents of the `ARCHIVE` attribute looks suspicious to me. Is it really supposed to be a comma-and-space delimited list? Also, the backslashes in front of the file names look suspicious:

```
ARCHIVE="\test.jar, \ojdbc14.signed.jar, \ojdbc14_g.signed.jar"
```

I would suggest you look into fixing the `ARCHIVE` attribute and then see if the web browser will load the class file form the jar as you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

the CODEBASE attribute is missing. just a thought.[code base](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/applets/_APPLET_CODEBASE.html)